# Process "loading" SCSS via Aurelia's CLI separately from bundle

Tags: bundling-and-minification, aurelia

Using Aurelia CLI with the built-in bundler and SystemJS ...

I have two SCSS files. One is for the loading indicator/page as Aurelia is bootstrapped and should be excluded from the bundle and available in my `/dist` folder as plain CSS (not bundled at all). I've accomplished the first part (excluding it from `app-bundle`), but how can I configure `au build` / `aurelia.json` to still process `loading.scss` and put the resulting CSS in `/dist`.

*Edit:* I can/will just update the appropriate gulp task myself, but was not sure if there was a better way.

Comment: I believe this might help? https://aurelia.io/docs/cli/cli-bundler/basics#copy-other-files-eg-fonts

Comment: Not exactly, since I need to pre-process the SCSS into CSS. Adding my own answer...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up altering the Gulp tasks to do what I needed to do. I verified on Aurelia's Gitter that this is the correct approach.